# Change variable in QThread

Tags: python-3.x, qthread, pyqt6

How to pass variable in already running QThread?
I need to change variable every 5 seconds.

```
class DoWork(QtCore.QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, variable):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.variable = variable
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.variable = "TEST":
                print("Variable not changed")
            else:
                print("Variable changed to : " + str(self.variable))
            sleep(1)

def runButton_OnClick(self):
    self.worker = DoWork("TEST")
    self.worker.start()
```

Comment: Use a QTimer, and connect it to a function that does `self.worker.variable = whatever`